# Filter results in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from table

name1  4 o
name1  5 x
name1  3 x
name2  3 x
name3  2 x
```

I have above results in that name1 have values 3,4 and 5 
I want to get the result as below where where the flag 'O' has been taken in case of multiple values for same name.here it is name1

```
name1  4 o
name2  3 x
name3  2 x
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you only have `o` and `x` as possible values? Might there be more than one `o` record for a particular name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `row_number` to select the lowest value of the `ox` column, like:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       row_number() over (partition by name order by ox asc) as rn
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

The subquery is required because you can't use `row_number` directly in a `where` clause.

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
No column was specified for column 24 of 'SubQueryAlias'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'rn'.

Comment: @user106528: Sorry, forgot to alias the row number to `rn`.  Fixed the answer now, does that work?